# Team Foundation Server 2018 - TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL mismatch

Tags: tfs, virtual-machine

I am just doing a trial upgrade of a TFS Server (2015) to TFS 2018 using the backup and restore to new hardware technique.

All has gone well, except using VS 2017 to connect to the TFS Server I get an error message as:

```
TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL did not match the expected value.
```

The value I have is Dev14.M114 and it should be DEV16.M122.5

Checking this against my baseline VM (which just had a standard 2018 fresh install) shows that it should be DEV16.M122.5

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue- I was thinking that after the migration, the databases need to be upgraded but can't see any instructions on doing this?

Comment: What's the result if you try to use web portal  to connect TFS instead of Visual Studio?

Comment: Any update on this issue, AndyW?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error info, your database on TFS2018 is still using TFS2015.

> The problem is that your team project collection databases **have to
>   be upgraded.** Pointing TFS 2018 to TFS 2015 project collection
>   databases without putting those databases through the normal process
>   of attaching them (and thus upgrading them) isn't going to work. In a
>   migration-based scenario, this is typically accomplished via the TFS
>   admin console.

Simply backup and restore the database to new hardware technique will not work. In you case, suggest you remapped old database to TFS2015, and then follow the  modern [upgrade documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/get-started).

Be careful of the [requirements and compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements#sql-server) with TFS2018, the SQL version on TFS2015 is not support. You need to move the databases to SQL 2016 (minimum SP1)or 2017 first. SQL will do the database upgrade, then you can run the TFS upgrade.

Also take a look at this similar issue: [TFS 2017 Error: TF401054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151504/tfs-2017-error-tf401054)

Comment: I did try to follow the upgrade information - however, it is incorrect in many aspects - unfortunately I do not have a GITHub so cannot submit feedback to the Microsoft documentation site.

Comment: @AndyW Thanks for the sharing. Since TFS2018 is a relative new production, some tips on the upgrade documentation may not fully applies to it. We are greet to hear your suggestion and content issue in the documentation. You could also submit your uservoice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services). TFS PM will also kindly review and listen your advice.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to open the TFS Admin tool and remove the TFS product (it leaves the databases) and then run it again but use the upgrade wizard.

Answer (score 0):

After I install AzureDevops server,I encountered the same problem。So I reinstalled and configured the existing database。

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)